# Right way to retrieve a ISO-8859-1 encoded website with LWP::UserAgent?

Tags: perl, encoding, iso-8859-1, lwp-useragent

I am retrieving a ´ISO-8859-1´ encoded website by using ´LWP::UserAgent´ with the following code.

The problem is, that the special characters are not displayed right, especialy the "€" sign is displayed wrong.

The content encoding is recognized as ´ISO-8859-1´, which is right.

To display the retrieved text I am saving it into a file and open it with Notepag++.

**Question:** How can I retrieve ´ISO-8859-1´ encoded special characters, in the right way?

```
#SENDING REQUEST
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
$ua->agent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1'); # pretend we are very capable browser

my $req = HTTP::Request->new(GET => $url);

#add some header fields
$req->header('Accept', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8');
$req->header('Accept-Language', 'en;q=0.5');
$req->header('Connection', 'keep-alive');
$req->header('Host', 'www.url.com');

#SEND
my $response = $ua->request($req);

#decode  trial1
print $response->content_charset(); # gives ISO-8859-1 which is right
my $content  = $response->decoded_content(); #special chars are displayed wrong

#decode trial2
my $decContent =  decode('ISO-8859-1', $response->content());
my $utf8Content = encode( 'utf-8', $decContent ); #special char € is displayed as Â

#decode trial3
Encode::from_to($content, 'iso-8859-1', 'utf8'); #special char € is displayed as Â too


#example on writing data to file
open(MYOUTFILE, ">>D:\\encodingperl.html"); #open for write, overwrite
print MYOUTFILE "$utf8Content"; #write text
close(MYOUTFILE);
```

Comment: You forgot to set your output encoding to utf8 by binmoding the output handle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same as any other:

```
my $content = $response->decoded_content();
```

That said, the [iso-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iso-8859-1) charset does not include the Euro sign. You probably actually have [cp1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252). You can fix that as follows:

```
my $content = $response->decoded_content( charset => 'cp1252' );
```

Your second problem is that you don't encode your output. This is how you'd do it.

```
open(my $MYOUTFILE, '>>:encoding(cp1252)', 'D:\\encodingperl.html')
   or die $!;
print $MYOUTFILE $content;
```

Use the encoding that's appropriate for you (e.g. `UTF-8`) if it's not `cp1252` you want. If you want the original file in the original encoding, use

```
my $content = $response->decoded_content( charset => 'none' );
```

and

```
open(my $MYOUTFILE, '>>', 'D:\\encodingperl.html')
   or die $!;
binmode($MYOUTFILE);
print $MYOUTFILE $content;
```

Comment: I didn't realize that `decoded_content` had that `charset` parameter; I was going to suggest using `content` plus a manual `Encode::decode`. Anyway, this is the correct answer, with the caveat that the encoding *could* be `ISO-8859-15` rather than `cp1252`.

Comment: @hobbs, I don't see how. iso-8859-15's "€" is `A4`. The browser would display `A4` as "¤" if told it was iso-8859-1. The only way the browser would display "€" when told it was iso-8859-1 is if it encountered `80`, cp1252's "€". Keep in mind that cp1252 is a superset of iso-8859-1.

Comment: @hobbs, Never use `content`. It doesn't get rid of some gzipping. If you wanted to manually decode, you'd use `my $content = decode(..., $response->decoded_content( charset => 'none' ));`.

Comment: Screwed-up websites like this are so common that the HTML5 spec instructs browsers to assume that any website that reports its content as ISO-8859-1 [is lying](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/parsing.html#character-encodings-0), and assume it's actually Windows-1252.

Comment: @cjm, cool, I didn't know that behaviour of browsers was standard. Is displaying the Euro symbol for `&#x80;` also dictated by HTML5?

Answer (score 0):

ISO-8859-1 doesn't have a euro symbol. If you need the euro symbol, you should either use ISO-8859-15 or, better yet, UTF-8.

Comment: Thnx but its not my website, so the encoding ISO-8859-1 I can not change. Somehow the browsers do display € right, even if it is not in ISO-8859-1. Is there a way to convert the whole string to UTF8 keeping € signs?

Comment: The browsers display the euro symbol with ISO-8859-1 at position 128. This is convenient, but technically wrong. What might work is recoding ISO-8859-1 to ISO-8859-15 replace all euro symbol characters 128 with 164 (the euro sign in ISO-8859-15) and recode that to UTF-8.